# forward и backward в ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, pjax

У меня есть страничка с товарами, которые фильтруются через ajax. Также меняется url через pushState. Но когда кликаешь по кнопкам назад и вперёд в браузере, ничего не происходит, меняется только url. Это можно как-то исправить?

Comment: Можно, начинайте исправлять :)

Comment: Если покажите код, который работает не так, как вы ожидаете, шансов, получить ответ, становится значительно больше

Comment: Ну а хоть кто-нибудь вообще пытается обрабатывать нажатие этих кнопок? У вас в метках стоит «pjax» — вы его правда каким-то образом подключили или просто метку для красоты поставили? Нужно больше подробностей и в идеале [mcve]

Comment: Я понимаю, что необязательно их обрабатывать, просто видел на многих сайтах и интересно как это работает.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event